# Tedious Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state

Tags: node.js, express, tedious

i'm trying to get some SQL connections to go on, but everytime I'm making a new request it keeps throwing an error:

RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Final state

I'm basically using these 3 functions for requests:

```
function executeStatementMultipleInsert(array) {
  request = new Request(
    `INSERT INTO tbs_nome (nome, cod)
        VALUES (@nome, @nome_cod)
        INSERT INTO tbs_sobrenome (sobrenome, cod) 
        VALUES (@sobrenome, @sobrenome_cod)
        INSERT INTO tbs_email (email, cod) 
        VALUES (@email, @email_cod)
      `,
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
  request.addParameter("nome", TYPES.NVarChar, array[0].nome);
  request.addParameter("nome_cod", TYPES.BigInt, array[0].cod);
  request.addParameter("sobrenome", TYPES.NVarChar, array[1].sobrenome);
  request.addParameter("sobrenome_cod", TYPES.BigInt, array[1].cod);
  request.addParameter("email", TYPES.NVarChar, array[2].email);
  request.addParameter("email_cod", TYPES.BigInt, array[2].cod);
  request.on("requestCompleted", () => {
    databaseConnection.close();
  });
  databaseConnection.execSql(request);
}

// Function to get the soma from queries

async function getSoma(tableName, cod) {
  return tp
    .sql(
      `DECLARE @tableName varchar(1000)
  SET @tableName = 'SELECT soma from tbs_cod_${tableName} WHERE cod=${cod}'
  EXEC (@tableName)`
    )
    .execute()
    .then((results) => {
      // do something with the results
      // console.log(results);

      databaseConnection.close();
      // console.log("database was closed");

      return results[0].soma;
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
      // do something with the failure
      console.log("nay" + err);
    });
}

async function getFinalResults(total) {
  console.log(total);
  let result = "";
  request = new Request(
    `SELECT a.animal, c.cor, p.pais 
    FROM tbs_animais AS a
    JOIN tbs_cores AS c ON a.total=c.total
    JOIN tbs_paises AS p ON a.total=p.total
    LEFT JOIN tbs_cores_excluidas AS ce ON a.total=ce.total
    WHERE a.total=@total`,
    function (err) {
      console.log("hey db");
      databaseConnection.close();
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  );
  request.addParameter("total", TYPES.BigInt, total);
  request.on('row', function(columns) {  
    columns.forEach(function(column) {  
      if (column.value === null) {  
        console.log('NULL');  
      } else {  
        console.log('not null');
        result+= column.value + " ";  
      }  
    });  
    console.log('hey');
    console.log('the result is ' + result);  
    result ="";  
});  
request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
  console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
  });
  databaseConnection.execSql(request);
}

const databaseConnection = new Connection(config);
```

while in my app.js I call them in some chain then statements. only the first post of the server gets inserted correctly, and when I get to my final request, a SELECT in the "getFinalResults" function, it throws me that error. This is some of my app.js file

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

// Post submit route
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  let codesArray = [
    {
      nome: req.body.nome,
    },
    {
      sobrenome: req.body.sobrenome,
    },
    {
      email: req.body.email,
    },
  ];
  let codesSum;
  // post para a API para obter o array de código
  axios
    .post("http://138.68.29.250:8082", qs.stringify(req.body), {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      codesSum = response.data.split(/[A-Za-z]*#/gi).filter(Boolean);
      codesArray.map((element, index) => {
        return (element.cod = Number(codesSum[index]));
      });
      // executeStatementMultipleInsert(codesArray);
      console.log(codesArray);
    })
    .then(async () => {
      for (let object of codesArray) {
        let soma = await getSoma(Object.keys(object)[0], object.cod);
        // console.log(soma);
        codesSum.push(soma);
      }
      // console.log(codesSum);
      let total = await codesSum
        .map((num) => Number(num))
        .reduce((acc, cv) => acc + cv);
        console.log(typeof total);
      let objectFinal = await getFinalResults(total);
      
      // console.log(objectFinal);
    })
    .catch((err) => {throw err});
  // connection to database
  databaseConnection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Connection failed");
      throw err;
    }
  });

  res.redirect("/");
});
```

i'm still having lots of trouble with asynchronicity and I suspect some of the issure might come from there? Or when I'm connecting and closing the connection to the database, which I'm also not sure is entirely correct